# Spring Data REST: use service instead of CrudRepository?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, repository, spring-data-rest

I'm just exploring the Spring Data REST library to build a REST API.

But in many examples I see that a REST API is generated from the CrudRepository.

I'm wondering if that is really useful in production? It seems to me that it is easy to get something up and running fast, but I would rather couple the REST API to a "true" service instead of "just" a repository.

What are your thoughts on this?

Kind regards,
B.

Answer (score 0):

**Repository** layer aimed to persist or retrieve your domain objects from database.

**Service layer** supposed to contain some business logic which is performed on domain objects.

If all you need is just obtain domain objects from database - you don't really need any services in your application. That's why many examples are generated from CrudRepository - this interface provides basic functionality for transferring data to/from database.

But if you need to perform some additional logic on objects beyond simple data transferring - you need a separate services.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom controller which use your service.

For example, a domain `Booking` and `BookingRepository`.

Please note that if you put `@RequestMapping(path = "bookings")`  on the controller, all the endpoints provided by Spring Data REST will be overridden and unaccessable. So put you `@RequestMapping` and its variances such as `@PutMapping` on the method.

If a controller method has `@PostMapping("bookings")`, then the `POST` endpoint provided by Spring Data REST will be replaced by this custom controller method.

```java
@RepositoryRestController
public class BookingController {

    private final BookingService bookingService;

    @PostMapping("/bookings")
    public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody Booking booking) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If a controller method has different request mapping path, then all endpoints provided by Spring Data REST are kept.

```java
@RepositoryRestController
public class BookingController {

    private final BookingService bookingService;

    @PutMapping("/bookings/{id}/confirm")
    public ResponseEntity confirm(@PathVariable String id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can find the full code of my `BookingController` on [Github](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/steins-gate-airline/blob/develop/booking/src/main/java/com/yejianfengblue/sga/booking/booking/BookingController.java)